# CentOS uEFI boot fails mounting correct drive: "/sysroot does not seem to be an os tree"

Tags: centos, mount, refind

I have just installed CentOS 7 on a MacBook Pro and ran the first post-installation boot from rEFInd using an SD Card. At the beginning the boot process seems to work, but it eventually fails with the message:

```
> Failed to switch root: Specified switch root path /sysroot does not seem to be an OS tree. os-release file is missing.
```

Then it fails back to the emergency shell.

After fiddling a bit I found by using `findmnt -lo source` that there were no physical drives mounted (`/dev/sdX`). So I took a guess and manually mounted my partition to `/sysroot` using:

```
mount -t ext4 --source /dev/sda4 --target /sysroot
```

…which succeeded. Then I quit the emergency shell and the system booted properly.

My problem seems to be simple (from the fact my first guess fixed the boot), but my searches through the internet have not yielded very useful results. The simple question is: what is wrong (or what should I look for) in my UEFI boot settings that are causing the correct drive to not mount, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It took me most of the day, but I came upon the following that worked for me:

```
genisoimage -U -r -v -T -J -joliet-long -V "CentOS 7 x86_64" -volset "CentOS 7 x86_64" -A "CentOS 7 x86_64" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -o ../new.iso .
```

> **Important note:**  the `-V`, `-volset` and `-A` params must match **LABEL=** value in the `isolinux/isolinux.cfg` file!!! (e.g. append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=**CentOS\x207\x20x86_64** quiet)

**See:** "https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/anaconda_customization_guide/sect-iso-images". See the "2.3. Creating Custom Boot Images" section.

The key thing I was missing was the correlation between the ISO label and the line for the bootloader. I too found no quick answers online until I found the right section of the redhat page.